# ThinkCell Automation through VBA

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I am looking for VBA codes to create think cell chart from excel ranges.

All  I found in the internet were VBA codes through which I can update a named thinkcell chart.

However I want the macro to create a new powerpoint and new thinkcell chart from my defined range.

Would that be possible?

Below is the code I found through which one can update Thinkcell chart, but not create a new thinkcell chart.

```
Sub UpdateThinkCellChart(Rng As Range, sChartName As String)


'Get the think-cell add-in object
Dim tcaddin As Object
Dim ppapp As Object
Dim pres As Object

Set tcaddin = Application.COMAddIns("thinkcell.addin").Object


'Set PowerPoint instance
'Set ppapp = New PowerPoint.Application

On Error Resume Next
Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

'Create PowerPoint presentation if none is open:
If ppapp Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No PowerPoint presentation is open. Please open the relevant presentation and ensure that you have pre-assigned chart names to your ThinkCell charts"
Exit Sub
End If

'Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set pres = ppapp.ActivePresentation


' The name sChartName must have been previously assigned to the chart using
' the control in the floating toolbar (left-click on the Think-Cell chart to see this)
' The final argument indicates whether the data range is transposed or not.
Call tcaddin.UpdateChart(pres, sChartName, Rng, False)


End Sub

Sub CopyToTC_ChartNo1()
Dim Rng As Range, sRange As String, sChartName As String

'Insert values:
sRange = "C21:F25"
sChartName = "ChartNo1"


Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(sRange)

Call UpdateThinkCellChart(Rng, sChartName)

End Sub
```

Comment: According to this line of code - `Set tcaddin = Application.COMAddIns("thinkcell.addin").Object` you *must* have the ThinkCell COM Add-in installed on your computer. That's the only way to create one of their charts. If the chart is something you could create manually, using the standard tools in Excel (which is what PowerPoint uses for charts) then it would probably be possible without that Add-in. But you'd need to figure out those steps and work out the code for them. The code snippet you show is useless without the Add-in.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
Just wanted to mention that the object can be added with that call line.
As mentioned by the thinkcell support people (https://www.think-cell.com/en/support/manual/programming.shtml).

This code that I have shown runs fine too, I just need the specific function for creating the chart.

Thanks again